# Gerrit: remote rejected (you are not allowed to upload merges) even though I allowed "Push merge commit"

Tags: gerrit

I've configured Gerrit to allow `Push Merge Commit` on my branch, but I still get the following error when I try to push a merge commit:

```
! [remote rejected] ANDROID-foo -> ANDROID-foo (you are not allowed to upload merges)
```

I'm running Gerrit 2.8-1-gaa9367b.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a [bug in gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1072). The [workaround](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repo-discuss/eClyladiNtY/JpMMO3YPeD8J) is to create another reference named `refs/for/refs/heads/<BRANCH_NAME>`, and allow `Push Merge Commit` on it.

To be more specifically, add following lines in your `project.config` file

```
[access "refs/for/refs/*"]
  pushMerge = group <your-id-here>
```

Comment: Note `refs/for/refs/heads/<BRANCH_NAME>`, i.e. plural 'heads' and not 'head'.

Comment: I do not understand how to do this. Can someone help ?

Comment: Sometimes I really hate gerrit for these long-standing bugs. Although I really like it, I can't really recommend it for enterprise use..

Answer (score 5):

Workaround which was more suitable for me as it doesn't involve knowing branches is to allow Push Merge Commit to `refs/for/refs/heads/*`. You probably won't want to be doing changing these for every branch specifically.

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me by this way(after this [link](https://blog.csdn.net/feather_wch/article/details/79231323)):

1. git stash
2. git pull --rebase
3. git push
4. git pull
5. git stash pop

Comment: "git pull --rebase" working here for me in such difficulty

Answer (score 1):

try to follow  these  steps:

[image]

try to apply these commands after shelving/stashing ur changes, once done, unshelve them and  commit / push

Answer (score -3):

First I reset the pointer to the commit of remote using soft mode, then I run

```
git add . 
git commit --amend
git push
```

It works for me. :)