# 'Your branch is ahead of 'origin/remote-branch' by 37 commit.' after merge

Tags: git, gerrit

**I have done the below steps:**

```
>git checkout remote-branch-test
>git pull
>git checkout remote-branch
>git pull
>git merge remote-branch-test
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

**resolved the conflict**

```
>git add .
>git commit
>git push origin remote-branch
**! [remote rejected]   remote-branch -> remote-branch (you are not allowed to upload merges)
error: failed to push some refs to ....
```

*When I do a git status on my remote server*

```
>git status
On branch remote-branch
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/remote-branch' by 37 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

**I am not able to push the changes to remote**

what I am missing here?

Comment: **remote rejected (you are not allowed to upload merges)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem by following Steps :

> git fetch

> git checkout origin/remote-branch

> git merge --squash origin/remote-branch-test

> git commit

> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/remote-branch

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to note here.  [phd pointed out the most important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540821/your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-remote-branch-by-37-commit-after-merge#comment122915777_69540821):

> ```
> [remote rejected] ... you are not allowed to upload merges
> ```

This tells us that your "remote"—the other Git to which you're sending commits—simply forbids *all merge commits*, period.

That particular error message, however, comes not from Git or GitHub, but from *Gerrit*.  See [Gerrit: remote rejected (you are not allowed to upload merges) even though I allowed "Push merge commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21199817/1256452) for example.  This implies that you're not using GitHub for your pushes.  Hence the [github](/questions/tagged/github) tag is probably inappropriate.  And, since Gerrit adds its own layer of stuff atop Git, the [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag may be inappropriate too.  I added [gerrit](/questions/tagged/gerrit) here, but you should make sure these are the correct tags and delete any inappropriate ones.

Finally, it's normal for a merge to add many commits: merge commits have two parents, and therefore adding one merge commit to some branch *B* will often add N+1 commits to *B*, where *N* is the number of commits reachable from the commit being merged but not from *B* itself before the merge.  So your merge merged an existing 36 commits, plus the merge itself, for 37 commits total.

Comment: Thanks @torek for suggestion for finding the root cause of the problem